# Jupyter notebook -plot overlay issue with combo chart of area and line chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I have 3 columns in my data frame - Year_MONTH, POP and MAX_RATE
When ploting, POPT-the dataframe with year_month on x- axis and max_rate as an line chart, POP as secondary axis with area chart.
I wrote this.

```
ax=POPT['MAX_RATE'].plot(kind='line', color="blue")
POPT[['POP']].plot(kind='area',color="orange", secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
```

[image]

here basically below line(MAX_RATE) is not seen
while I do other way round

```
ax = POPT[['POP']].plot(kind='area',secondary_y=True,color="orange")
POPT['MAX_RATE'].plot(kind='line', color='blue', xlim=ax.get_xlim())
```

this generates like this

[image]

here i cant see the line as it is not in the frame or primary y axis is not showing properly.

when I wrote like this

```
POPT['MAX_RATE'].plot(kind='line', color="blue")
POPT[['POP']].plot(kind='area', secondary_y=True)
```

this just split as two seperate charts
how do I correct this?

Comment: i've switched fully to always using `fig, ax = sublots(1, 1)`, there is problably a better way to do it, but it does the trick. After declaring figure and axis object, use the plot on the axis

Comment: also, add some alpha to your plot, it migh help

Comment: With the second attempt, try `ax.set_ylim(top=6)`

Comment: @BigBen  It might work for this example but the scale might change and I dont want to always change according to the data

Comment: Then perhaps use `POPT['MAX_RATE'].max()` plus some adjustment.

Comment: @Felício I see the secondary y axis is 0 starts a little above the primary y axis 0. Is it possible to make it consistant

Comment: you should be able to change everything on all the axis's on that ax object, can't remember the syntax by heart thou, ggit